# Missing default constructor for StackTrace in netstandard 1.5

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, system.diagnostics

I am facing difficulties using StackTrace from within a netstandard 1.5 project. It appears to be missing the default constructor which works fine in netcore 3.1 projects.

The error is:

```
error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
parameter 'exception' of 'StackTrace.StackTrace(Exception, bool)'
```

There is no dedicated API page indicating what the API actually is, instead it shows netcore 3.1 which does have a default constructor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-1.5

If I view source in Rider then I see the same API as 3.1.

`.cspproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.5</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.StackTrace" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`Program.cs`

```cs
using System;

namespace stacktracer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Can I create a StackTrace in netstandard without an Exception?

Answer (score 0):

`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` is not a part of .NET Standard 1.5.

You can find the complete API [here on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.5_ref.md).

Alternatively, you can use the [.NET API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-1.5).

.NET Standard 2.1, however, *does* include this API.

Comment: It's coming from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace which has netstandard 1.3 interface. The type can be used, it just has odd constructors.